# WinSCPのopenコマンドを打つだけで、認証後、ディレクトリ への移動エラーとなる

Tags: ftp, winscp

**WinSCPで、openコマンドの動作確認したいだけなのですが、意図せずディレクトリ へ移動しようとしてエラー表示されます**

・認証自体は可
・このエラー表示以外は普通に動作します
・何かの設定ですか？

---

> winscp> open IPアドレス:ポート番号 -privatekey=パス

```
サーバを探索中･･･
サーバに接続しています･･･
認証しています･･･
ユーザ名(U): hoge
公開鍵 "" で認証中
認証されました
セッションを開始しています･･･
ディレクトリ '/var/www/example' への移動のエラー。
パス '/var/www/example' を取得できません
そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
エラー コード: 2
 からのエラー メッセージ: No such file
セッションを開始しました
アクティブ セッション: [1] IPアドレス
```

---

**環境**
・WinSCP 5.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いったんGUIで「新しいセッション」タブをクリックし、「ログイン」ダイアログが表示されたら
「新しいサイト」をクリック、接続するプロトコルを選んで「設定...」ボタンを押します。

「環境」->「ディレクトリ」で「最後に使用したディレクトリを記憶する」の**チェックを外し**
ひとつ前の画面に戻ったら「管理」ボタンをクリックし、「デフォルトの設定として使う」を
クリックします。

**「ログイン」ダイアログ**
[image: ログイン ダイアログ]

**「高度なサイトの設定」ダイアログ**
[image: 高度なサイトの設定 ダイアログ]

**デフォルトの設定として扱う**
[image: デフォルトの設定として扱う]

Comment: 期待した通り動作するようになりました！